# Does % in like clause of SQL greedy in nature like .*?

Tags: sql, sql-like, regex

I have sql like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where username like '%ash%';
```

I know when we use normal regex `.*` us greedy in nature & it back track if something is after `.*` try to match next things. Is is same with SQL internals?

Comment: SQL internals? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: In general, what is paradigm used? I have worked with multiple like oracle, PostgreSQL, hive, presto but never got the reference like how internally it's implemented

Comment: In general products have their own code, so there is no general answer.

Comment: However, the leading % wildcard is the problem here, making index usage much harder.

Comment: Interesting question. I would tend to think it's greedy, though I don't think the behavior is relevant for the query executiion. As soon as a match is found the predicate is considered true and the query applies it. If you were extracting matches or sub-groups that would be meaningful, but this this is not the case with the `LIKE` operator.